# Can't get callback from HTTP method in controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, razor, model-view-controller

I'm busy creating a wait indicator for uploading files but it seems like I can't receive any callback from the POST method that's getting triggered in the controller. I've been searching for half a day and tried a lot of different solutions but none of them seem to work in my case.

I have a model:

```
public class FileUploadModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select file(s) to upload.")]
    [Display(Name = "Browse")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase[] Files { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "File Type")]
    public EFileType FileType{ get; set; }
}
```

I have a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileExchange", "General", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "uploadform" }))
```

Method in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> FileExchange(FileUploadModel model)
{
    await UploadFiles(model);
    return View("FileExchange");
}
```

And I have tried something like the following in javascript/ajax:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#preloader").hide(); //the wait indicator
        $('#uploadform').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var formdata = new FormData($('#uploadform').get(0));

            $("#preloader").show();

            var url = '@Url.Content("~/General/FileExchange/")'
            //var dataModel = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: formdata,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                //dataType: "json",
                success: function (resp) {
                    $("#preloader").hide();
                },
                error: function (resp) {
                    $("#preloader").hide();
                }
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

The wait indicator is working BUT the method isn't getting hit.

When I add the model to the on 'submit' function:

`$('#uploadform').on('submit', model, function (e)`

the POST method gets hit but the wait indicator stopped working. Almost seems like the on 'submit' function doesn't get hit anymore.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: `$('uploadform')` is invalid selector that looks for a tag `<uploadForm>`. For an id should be `$('#uploadform')`. Since is inside submit handler for that form can just do `var formdata = new FormData(this);`

Comment: fixed the selector and nothing changed. Also tried `var formdata = new FormData(this);` POST method is not getting hit.

Comment: Removing `"FileExchange", "General", FormMethod.Post,` from the form is not helping either. POST method in the controller is getting hit but the files aren't passed correctly to my model.

Comment: Break down where the problems might be and tackle them each invidually. My first check would be to make sure the request is definitely going to the server you expect. I would use an HTTP proxy to check the traffic.

Comment: Seems like it's not possible to pass a model with files within ajax. Close it please. I have to find a different way to receive a callback from the controller to update the wait indicator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching for a bit longer and I found a solution to my issue:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#preloader").hide();
    })

    $('#uploadform').on('submit', function () {

        $("#preloader").show();

        $('#uploadform').ajaxForm({
            url: '@Url.Content("~/General/FileExchange")',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function () {
                $("#preloader").hide();
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

This way I can show the indicator when the on 'submit' is triggered and hides the indicator when the POST method from the given URL is successfully executed.